# Gulp 4 watch task stuck on 'Starting'

Tags: gulp

So mine is a pretty simple gulp file.

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const ap = require("gulp-autoprefixer");

function styles() {
  return gulp
    .src("./style.css")
    .pipe(ap("last 2 versions"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist"));
}

function watch() {
  gulp.watch("./style.css", styles);
}

exports.watch = watch;
exports.styles = styles;

exports.default = watch;
```

Running the styles task independently does produce the autoprefixed css.

The watch task however gets stuck on `Starting 'watch'...`

Can someone tell me what's wrong.

Gulp CLI Version: 2.0.1
Gulp Local Version: 4.0.0
Node: 10.15.0
OS: Windows 10 (WSL)

Comment: Try   gulp.watch("./style.css", gulp.series(styles));  in your watch function.  It "should" work without the series but doesn't seem to.

Comment: Note that your `watch` task will only run when the file changes. Do you mean that the `styles` task doesn't run when you alter and save the file?

Comment: `gulp.series(styles))` doesn't work.

Comment: @TheDancingCode, when the watch task is run, Gulp should tell me that it is watching the glob. Instead it is just stuck at "Starting 'watch'..."

Comment: That is the normal behaviour. The `styles` task won't run when you start the `watch` task, but only when you change and save the `style.css` file.

Answer (score 1):

This might be an old question but I encountered the same issue when upgrading an old project from gulp 3 to gulp 4. I had a watcher that should start before a server spun up but I got stuck at `Starting 'watch'...`

I could fix it by passing a `done` callback to the watcher task and calling it after the watch command. This led the server to start after it gets noticed that the watcher went through, like so:

```
    gulp.task('serve', gulp.series(['task1', 'task2'], function (done) {
        gulp.watch(['src/**/*.js']);
        gulp.watch(['src/**/*.less']);
        done(); // <-- this one
    }));
```